# Moderation on Open Data: We need candidates to step up for an election

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

It is Stack Exchange's stance that every site needs to have a team of moderators in order to continue existing on the network. Open Data currently has two moderators: [Patrick Hoefler](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/70/patrick-hoefler) and [philshem](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/1511/philshem), who have done a wonderful job moderating Open Data over the years. They have both indicated that they are ready for a break and would like to step down as moderators. They have both agreed to stay on until an election can be scheduled.

We need users who are willing to step up and run in a Pro-Tem election in order to have moderators on the site and for the site to continue operating. We need at least 2-3 users willing to run in an election and to serve as a moderator if elected/appointed (depending on how many candidates run).

Any community member in good standing with more than 300 reputation (and who is at least 18 years old) may nominate themself to be a community moderator. If you want to know what goes into being a moderator, see this Help Center page: [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

**If you would be interested in nominating yourself in an election, please post an answer here to let us know.** This will help us gauge interest so we can work with the current moderators on scheduling an election for early fall.

Comment: I've been in touch with Patrick and philshem. We're tentatively looking at mid-September for running an election.